# Apple sign in - Multiple iphone Apps, Different App ID, Same Server

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-sign-in, apple-developer

We have 2 apps setup for Apple Sign in. (A and B)

App A already works fine and Sign in with Apple is successful.

Our (Python/Django) server is already setup properly for App A with the necessary keys from apple.

But since Keys only work for one AppID, I'd like to know how to configure our server or our apps to allow for Apple sign in on both app A and B with our server.

Any suggestions on where to look?

I've tried the idea of selecting "Group with an existing primary App ID" on Sign In with Apple: App ID Configuration for App B identifier but it doesn't work